# Dask fails to read file while Pandas not

Tags: python, pandas, dask

I was previoulsy using pandas to read and process data, having some memory issues. I could read a big file with:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('mydata.csv.gz', sep=';')
```

However, when doing the same with Dask, I get an error:

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
df_base = dd.read_csv('CoilsSampleFiltered.csv.gz', sep=';')
```

Traceback:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-abc513f2a657> in <module>()
----> 1 df_base = dd.read_csv('CoilsSampleFiltered.csv.gz', sep=';')

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dask\dataframe\io\csv.py in read(urlpath, blocksize, collection, lineterminator, compression, sample, enforce, assume_missing, storage_options, **kwargs)
    424                            enforce=enforce, assume_missing=assume_missing,
    425                            storage_options=storage_options,
--> 426                            **kwargs)
    427     read.__doc__ = READ_DOC_TEMPLATE.format(reader=reader_name,
    428                                             file_type=file_type)

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dask\dataframe\io\csv.py in read_pandas(reader, urlpath, blocksize, collection, lineterminator, compression, sample, enforce, assume_missing, storage_options, **kwargs)
    324 
    325     # Use sample to infer dtypes
--> 326     head = reader(BytesIO(b_sample), **kwargs)
    327 
    328     specified_dtypes = kwargs.get('dtype', {})

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in parser_f(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col, date_parser, dayfirst, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands, decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, escapechar, comment, encoding, dialect, tupleize_cols, error_bad_lines, warn_bad_lines, skipfooter, skip_footer, doublequote, delim_whitespace, as_recarray, compact_ints, use_unsigned, low_memory, buffer_lines, memory_map, float_precision)
    707                     skip_blank_lines=skip_blank_lines)
    708 
--> 709         return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    710 
    711     parser_f.__name__ = name

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    447 
    448     # Create the parser.
--> 449     parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
    450 
    451     if chunksize or iterator:

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in __init__(self, f, engine, **kwds)
    816             self.options['has_index_names'] = kwds['has_index_names']
    817 
--> 818         self._make_engine(self.engine)
    819 
    820     def close(self):

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in _make_engine(self, engine)
   1047     def _make_engine(self, engine='c'):
   1048         if engine == 'c':
-> 1049             self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)
   1050         else:
   1051             if engine == 'python':

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in __init__(self, src, **kwds)
   1693         kwds['allow_leading_cols'] = self.index_col is not False
   1694 
-> 1695         self._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, **kwds)
   1696 
   1697         # XXX

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._get_header()

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 1: invalid start byte
```

I'm trying to figure it out what's the problem. The file was written by R, which uses utf-8 by default.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not reading a csv file. Pandas probably had auto-detected the compression. If you want to use dask you need to specify the compression scheme.

```
df = dd.read_csv("CoilsSampleFiltered.csv.gz", compression='gzip')
```

Comment: Thank you. I though it would infer as pandas.